# Is the "image name" specified in the Windows command "taskkill /im" the name of the executable file in task manager or is it something else?

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-8.1, cmd.exe

My issue is that Windows file explorer has crashed during a file transfer. To help alleviate this type of issue, I have set in the File and Folder Options for each instance of explorer.exe to run in it’s own separate process so if one crashes, all of explorer, at least in theory, will not crash as well. Now I have two explorer.exe’s running in task manager. One is the file transfer, and it is not doing anything but it’s still responding in task manager at least. The other is just an open folder and it is crashed completely and not responding. Right clicking and saying kill process does nothing. The PID of the working window is 9077 and the PID of the crashed window 9076. If I type “taskkill /PID 9076” it says it cant kill it because that PID is not running. I want to see if “/IM” will help kill the one but not the other, but I might have a problem with that if “Image Name” means the executable name, because both Explorer tasks have the same image name then, “explorer.exe”.

Comment: The diff between crash/hang is important.  If a process crashes, it terminates, in this scenario you typically want to obtain a dump of the process.  Easiest way, register ProcDump [https://docs.microsoft.com/sysinternals/downloads/procdump] as the postmortem debugger.  `mkdir C:\dumps` `procdump -ma -i c:\dumps`. Whenever a process crashes you'll get a full dump.  If a process hangs, then you also want to create a dump or 3, but this would be manually initiated.  E.g. `procdump -s 5 -n 3 notepad`, taking a number of dumps enables you to check progress.  Also consider the -mk switch.

Comment: I enetually just hard rebooted the computer and started the file transfer over, but I have setup to use this process the next time it happens. I get this every month or two. Thanks for the tip!